# Autohotkey: Shift and caps lock

Tags: autohotkey

So I wanted to print < when pressing caps lock and > when holding shift and hitting caps lock. For some reason > won't get printed when I use the code below:

```
CapsLock::
    If GetKeyState("Shift")
    Send, >
    else
    Send, <
Return
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this in the same number of lines?

```
CapsLock::
    Send, <
Return

+CapsLock::
    Send, >
Return
```

Additionally, if you want to preserve the functionality of Capslock and Shift, add a tilde beforehand:

```
~CapsLock::
    Send, <
Return

~+CapsLock::
    Send, >
Return
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @David's answer which is the correct way to do it, your code doesn't work because you defined `CapsLock` as a hotkey which means it's not going to fire when shift is pressed. Adding `*` to your hotkey: `*CapsLock::` will make it fire regardless of modifiers and your code will work.